# Tomcat7 autorefresh server-status and explanation

Tags: tomcat7

two questions regarding tomcat7 admin-manager. I´m trying to find a bottleneck with slow response times. Therefore I´ve enabled tomcat7 admin host manager. Mainly I´m interested in the status of incoming requests which can be seen by visiting /manager/status/all

[image]

**Question 1:**
Is it possible to "auto refresh" the status of the requests or even look at it in terminal? With apache I´m just doing `watch apachectl status`

**Question 2:**

How to understand `29 Rejected session creations` mean by looking at a depoyed tomcat app (geoserver) within serverlist.

```
 Active sessions: 29 Session count: 29 Max active sessions: 29 Rejected session creations: 0 Expired sessions: 0 Longest session alive time: 0 s Average session alive time: 0 s Processing time: 0 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Question 2: read the statistics correctly, perhaps like this:

```
 Active sessions: 29
 Session count: 29
 Max active sessions: 29
 Rejected session creations: 0
 Expired sessions: 0
 Longest session alive time: 0 s
 Average session alive time: 0 s
 Processing time: 0 ms
```

Don't worry, be happy.

Regarding Question 1: I always use the locahost-access logs.

Comment: Thanks Gerard! Regarding 1: Can you share how? tail -f  ... ?

Comment: I would'nt last 5 minutes.  I've got two tomcats load-balanced running 50 applications, they handle 120.000 requests per hour, webservices. So tail -f is quite useless.  I use the  localhost_access_logs if I need statistics, or to verify the response times of a specific application.